# When number is not found in array it does not give me the desired output

Tags: c, binary-search

Below code finds the desired key in array and prints it but when key is not found, I expect the search return -1 and print "Key not found." But this is not printed. Is there a mistake?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int binarySearch(int* arr, int size, int key){

    int low=0;
    int high=size-1;
    int mid=(low+high)/2;      

    while(arr[mid]!=key){
    
        if(key>arr[mid]){
            low=mid+1;
            mid=(low+high)/2;
        }
        if(key<arr[mid]){
            low=0;
            high=mid-1;
            mid=(low+high)/2;       
        }   
        if(key==arr[mid]){
            return mid;
        }           
    }   
}

int main(){

    int intArr[10]={4,5,12,44,232,326,654,776,987,999};

    int res=binarySearch(intArr, 10, 1);

    if(res){
        printf("Key found at index: %d.", res);
    }else ("Key not found.");
}
```

Note: I made a mistake on syntax of this part. I corrected.

this

```
else ("Key not found.");
```

to

```
else (printf("Key not found.\n"));
```

It is working as intended after this correction. I also added @weatherwane' s suggestion and @poepew's suggestions.

Here is the working code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int binarySearch(int* arr, int size, int key){
    
    int low=0;
    int high=size-1;
    int mid=(low+high)/2;
    
    while(high-low>0){
        
        if(key>arr[mid]){
            low=mid+1;
            mid=(low+high)/2;
        }
        if(key<arr[mid]){
            low=0;
            high=mid-1;
            mid=(low+high)/2;       
        }   
        if(key==arr[mid]){
            return mid;
        }           
    }   
    return -1;
}

int main(){
    
    int intArr[10]={4,5,12,44,232,326,654,776,987,999};
    
    int res=binarySearch(intArr, 10, 43);
    
    if(res>=0){
        printf("Key found at index: %d.\n", res);
    }
    else (printf("Key not found.\n"));
}
```

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Unrelated: `int i,j;` is not needed as you've not used `i` and `j`.

Comment: `else ("Key not found.");` isn't valid C. Also, always ensure your final output ends with a `'\n'`, e.g. `printf("Key found at index: %d.\n", res);` and `puts (Key not found.");` so your program is POSIX compliant.

Comment: The function does not deal with the case where the key is not found. `while(arr[mid]!=key)` ==> `while(high - low > 0)`

Comment: Why will `mid` (the value usually, but not always, returned) ever be `-1`? The range `low` and `high` are always positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation of an *iterative* bsearch using the test `while (arr[mid] != key)`, is a bit awkward compared to the normal loop condition of `while (low <= high)`, but you can write it this way.

You have three exit conditions to protect against:

1. `key` is less than 1st element in array,
2. `key` is greater than last element in array, and
3. `key` is within the range of 1st - last, but not present in the array.

The primary error in your logic is you only adjust `low` if `key > arr[mid]`, and you only adjust `high` if `key < arr[mid]`. You never adjust both in response to a condition.

Putting it altogether, you would edit your approach and do:

```c
int binarySearch (int *arr, int size, int key) {

  int low = 0,
      high = size - 1,
      mid;

  while (arr[mid] != key) {       /* loop while key not found */
  
    if (low > high) {             /* all possible values searched */
      return -1;                  /* return key not found */
    }
    
    mid = (low + high) / 2;       /* compute mid once per-iteration */
    
    if (key > arr[mid]) {
      low = mid + 1;              /* only adjust low if key > element */
    }
    else if (key < arr[mid]) {
      high = mid - 1;             /* only adjust high if key < element */
    }
  }
  
  return mid;                     /* return index to key */
}
```

The traditional implementation of a bsearch controlling the loop with `low <= high` is written as follows:

```c
int binarySearch (int *arr, int size, int key)
{
  int low = 0,
      high = size - 1,
      mid;

  while (low <= high) {
      
      mid = low + ((high - low) / 2);
      
      if (arr[mid] == key) {
          return mid;
      }
      else if (key < arr[mid]) {
          high = mid - 1;
      }
      else {
          low = mid + 1;
      }
  }

  return -1;
}
```

You would need to dump to assembly to determine which provided the most efficient implementation. They will be within a few instructions of each other.

Let me know if you have questions.

(**note:** while the compiler may not care if there are no spaces in your code, your aging professor will -- always space your code adequately for readability)

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because you do not have a return statement for the so called 'not found' case. After your while statement add a return -1 case.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int binarySearch(int* arr, int size, int key){

    int low=0;
    int high=size-1;
    int mid=(low+high)/2;  
    int i = 0;

    while(arr[mid]!=key ){
        i = mid;
        if(key>arr[mid]){
            low=mid+1;
            mid=(low+high)/2;
        }
        if(key<arr[mid]){
            low=0;
            high=mid-1;
            mid=(low+high)/2;       
        }   
        if(key==arr[mid]){
            return mid;
        }    
        if(i == mid){
            return -1;
        }
    }   
    return -1;
}

int main(){

    int intArr[10]={4,5,12,44,232,326,654,776,987,999};

    int res=binarySearch(intArr, 10, 99);
    typeof(res);
    if(res){
        printf("Key found at index: %d.", res);
    }
    else {
        printf("Key not found");
        
    }
}
```

EDIT: Also there was an infinite loop caused by the while loop, in order for the while loop presented in the question arr[mid] should not be equal to the key. which if the array does not contain the wanted element results in infinite loop. The solution I have added is to check if the new mid value is added or not. it is set to the initial value at the start of the loop and if it is not muted, it returns -1.

Comment: When I run a compilation of the OP's code, it hangs. The function does not return at all. Whatever (rogue) value the function returns, `main` reports something.

Comment: I have edited the answer accordingly, the problem is quitting the while loop. You can ask following questions about the answer if you have any.

Comment: You have introduced another fault in `main`, because the not-found value  `-1` is `true`. And if the key was found at index `0` then the report will be "Not found" :) You have changed the condition `if(res>=0)` for no good reason. Please *test* solutions you post.